# Retrieving data without refreshing the page with ajax in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I can post with ajax, but when I want to pull data without refreshing the page, I can only do it 2 times, then the button loses its function.

```
<div>
  <input type="hidden" name="producecode" class="pcode" value="{{per.produceCode}}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="useremail" class="uponequantity" value="{{user.username}}" />
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary upoq"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

and jquery

```
$(".upoq").on("click", function() {
  $(".uponequantity").attr("value", localStorage.getItem('key'));
  var producecode = $(this).parent().find(".pcode").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/uponequantity/",
    headers: {
      "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}'
    },
    data: {
      "producecode": $(this).parent().find(".pcode").val(),
      "useremail": $(".uponequantity").val(),
    },
    success: function() {
      //window.location.assign('/basket/'+"?b="+$(".uponequantity").val());
      $.ajax({
        url: '/basket/' + "?b=" + $(".uponequantity").val(),
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(result) {
          $('.basket').html(result);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This needs more information. What do you mean with *loses its function*? You speak about getting data without refreshing the page, but you have `window.location.assign` in your code, which refreshes the page. What is it for? Where in your code is the click event listener for the button?

Comment: actually i can't use the ajax GET method because it is rendering the whole page i need some values

Comment: Where is the `.basket` element in your HTML? Is the `.upoq` element a descendant of `.basket`?

Comment: The GET method only decides *how* you make the request. Your Django code decides what to return. If you request a page, then you'll get a page. If you only want some values, then you could create an endpoint that only gives you these values.

Comment: yes .upoq element include data. Thank you for your advices

Comment: You're welcome. So, I think the problem is that `$('.basket').html(result);` replaces a lot of HTML in your page, including the `.upoq` element. That means that the `.upoq` will be replaced with a new `.upoq` element. This new element does not have an event listener (`$(".upoq").on("click", ...`). So it *looks like* the `.upoq` element does not work anymore, but in reality you created a new element without that doesn't do anything when clicked. But this is with the assumption that the `.upoq` element is inside the `.basket` element.